# Is it possible to upload/publish an unlisted extension via the chrome webstore api?

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, chrome-web-store

We are hoping to upload a chrome extension and publish it as unlisted (as the visibility option) via the Chrome Webstore Api.

So far we have been able to upload but not publish using [this documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/webstore_api/items/insert) -- we can't publish because extensions have a whole bunch of required parameters (like a screenshot or small-tile image) which we can't figure out how to attach. We are really hoping that one of these parameters will be visibility, and we can set it to "unlisted".

If any kind soul has any knowledge of the Chrome Webstore API, or how to set these parameters, our whole development team would be very appreciative.

The documentation on this is very sparse: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/webstore_api/items/update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [Using the Chrome Web Store Publish API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api):

> Note: Currently, there is no API for setting an item’s metadata, such as description. This has to be done manually in the [Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard). More detail about the Web Store API can be found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/api_index).

So, to the question whether you can supply all the metadata programmatically - the answer is "no". And the `Publish` method does not seem to support "unlisted".

Comment: Theoretically shouldn't it be possible to write a script that issues the appropriate http requests to effectively log into the Developer Dashboard, and change the metadata? It won't be as clean as an API but it should be possible.

Comment: @advait Theoretically, yes, but it's not a in the scope of the question.

Comment: @advait yeah, one actually can create a chrome extension that will do those scripting actions (login to the dashboard and past the values) - a chrome extension that releases other chrome extensions :)