# Publish Unlisted Chrome Extension via Chrome webstore Api

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I have completely read the following documentation:
[Publish API Doc](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api)

Looks like there is only 2 options, Publishing an item to the public and Publishing an item to trusted users. No mention of unlisted extension publish.

Can we some how publish an unlisted chrome extension via the webstore api?

Answer (score -1):

In essence, unlisted chrome extension are already published apps, albeit they're not PUBLICLY published. [Only people with a direct link](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2663860?hl=en) can access the apps.

You may also check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929790/is-it-possible-to-upload-publish-an-unlisted-extension-via-the-chrome-webstore-a) for additional insight.